# Is it a good idea to use neosporin for opened blisters?

Tags: dermatology, wound-care, neosporin, blister

Is it a good idea to use neosporin for opened blisters?

Example of opened blisters:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [its description](https://www.drugs.com/mtm/neosporin-topical.html), Neosporin *can* be used for minor cuts and scrapes, which seem to fit well to your description of opened blister.

The picture provided shows a shallow opening. I doubt something like that would be much of a concern. It would be better to cleanly cut of the loose cut skin to a comfortable level and wait for the healing process to complete. 
If the loose skin is left uncut, it would have the risk of becoming a handle to rip the skin further. If the wound is deeper, then treat the wound [as prescribed](https://www.drugs.com/cdi/neosporin-ointment.html).

Answer (score 4):

[See this from the AAD about wound care.](https://www.aad.org/public/skin-hair-nails/injured-skin/wound-care)

[See this from Medscape for interesting info on wound healing.](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/884594-overview#showall)

1. Studies are mixed whether there are clear improved outcomes from using antibiotic ointments (like neosporin) over petroleum jelly (like vaseline) on wounds that are cleaned and kept clean. There is a little more evidence for benefit in wounds acquired in dirty circumstances, and in partial thickness burns.
2. That article, as well as all dermatologists I work with, recommend sterile petroleum jelly (or antibiotic ointment) to SCAR less than using nothing, and say it may heal faster.
3. Since it has medication in it, antibiotic ointment can have more side effects (like allergic reactions); it's not without risk. Petroleum jelly has no active ingredients.
4. Always keep it covered with a clean bandaid for 24-48 hrs.
5. You can use neosporin (or vaseline) on shallow open wounds safely if you have no allergic reaction to it.  (If it goes down to fascia/muscle/bone, don't - but you should be in a medical office having that looked at anyway.)
6. TRY TO NEVER POP BLISTERS.  A blister is sterile inside until you puncture it, which lets tons of bacteria come party inside your body.  (And viruses, and fungus, and...)
7. If a blister pops, try to wash the area with soap/water, lay the skin back down to cover it, and put a bandaid on - with or without vaseline or antibiotic ointment.
8. Tip: Use vaseline tubes to deposit a dab onto the clean bandaid, QTip, or a tissue to be more sanitary.
9. For my 2 cents, I prefer using vaseline and a clean bandaid.  If it was a dirty wound or large deroofed blister, after washing it, I may use antibiotic ointment for first 24 hrs as if it were a burn.